# TensorFlow: Can't invoke streaming_sparse_precision_at_k

Tags: initialization, tensorflow, precision

Upon trying to calculate precision@k, I get an exception. To what follows is the a simple code that reproduces the problem.

First the code defines the variable scope:

```
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1, seed=1234)
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer)
```

Then it calls those lines:

```
predictions = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2, 10], tf.int64))
labels = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2, 1], tf.int64))
precision = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_sparse_precision_at_k(predictions, labels, 5)
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
```

(I know this code is meaningless, and tries to calculate the precision given 2 fixed matrices...)

Then I get the following exception:

> W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:936] Failed precondition:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value
>   model/precision_at_5/false_positive_at_5   [[Node:
>   model/precision_at_5/false_positive_at_5/read = IdentityT=DT_DOUBLE,
>   _class=["loc:@model/precision_at_5/false_positive_at_5"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]

The same goes when I tried to invoke `streaming_sparse_recall_at_k` instead of `streaming_sparse_precision_at_k`.
The installed version is r0.10 on linux with python 2.7.

Please help... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you initialize your variables? Try adding a line like "sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())" where "sess" is the name of your Tensorflow session.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but I also called the line tf.initialize_all_variables().run(). I updated my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if you intended this, but you must run initialize_all_variables() *after* creating the variables. Try putting the initialize_all_variables() invocation after you've finished building the whole graph.

Comment: Didn't work neither :(
Maybe because streaming_sparse_precision_at_k defines 2 local variables, there should be another initialization for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`tf.initialize_all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#initialize_all_variables) doesn't initialize "local" variables (which tend to be internal implementation details for ops like [`tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_sparse_precision_at_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.metrics.html#streaming_sparse_precision_at_k) and [`tf.train.string_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer), as opposed to variables used as model weights).

You'll need to add a line to your program that runs [`tf.initialize_local_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#initialize_local_variables) before running the evaluation op:

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())  # or `tf.initialize_local_variables().run()`
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Tiny comment: brackets are missing in this code snippet, and it should be `tf.initialize_local_variables().run()`

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the code snippet to fix the typo - thanks for pointing that out!